# Will upgrading to Windows 8 lose Google Chrome Auto-Complete Emails/Usernames?

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, passwords

I'm upgrading a users computer to Windows 8 and I plan to use the option to keep files and applications, will Google Chrome still remember email addresses the user starts type in or will they need to all be written down? (There's a lot of them!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you plan to use the option *Keep files and applications*, thus an in-place upgrade, you **should not** lose any of your application data associated with that user.

**However**, you could recommend that your friend signs in with her Google account, as to synchronize these forms. That way, even if the upgrade fails, you'll still have your data.

**Otherwise**, you **can also per the other answer simply copy your user data folder**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading your windows all the data in your previous windows installation will be moved to "windows.old" folder. All the data will be moved there so when you install google again then you can transfer that data from the old installation to the new installation. Also all the data that chrome saves to is saved inside this folder "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" and that the folder Appdata is hidden so you would need to unhide your files and folder. So you just need to copy "User data" folder from windows.old folder(find "User data" folder) to the current folder.

For eg. if your installation drive is C: drive then copy "C:\Windows.old\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" folder to "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" and then restart chrome. Also after you save necessary data from the previous installation you can delete it by clean drive your windows installation drive.